# Print Bartender File

Tags: c#, bartender

I am looking to print a bartender file with a C# app.

I have the code:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Seagull\BarTender 2021\BarTend.exe /F=C:\Labels\test.btw /P");
```

But gives the output

> The system cannot find the file specified

Everything is there, spelled correctly. It seems like a simple mistake but not sure where it is, since the documentation is very minimal

I have tried to just go step by step, so I removed everything after the `BarTend.exe`, and the program launches. So the issue is with the `/F=C:\Labels\test.btw`. Not sure where to go now.

Answer (score 3):

`Process.Start` expects only the file name of your program as it's first argument. If your program needs parameters you have to pass them as a separate argument:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Seagull\BarTender 2021\BarTend.exe", @"/F=C:\Labels\test.btw /P");
```